# loop over the object returned by the class to get the id

Tags: java

I have the following code and running into some issues:

```
List<String> locationList = locmgr.getEmployeeLocationByQuery("name LIKE'"+searchName+"%'");
System.out.println("print location");
System.out.println(locationList);

for (String list : locationList) {
System.out.println("Inside Loop");
System.out.println(list);
}
```

The print statements above the for loop are printing the following:

```
[INFO]  print location
[INFO]  [EmployeeLocation [id=83, name=firstname, description=tetetyet, comment=, locationId=6], EmployeeLocation [id=84, name=secondname, description=test, comment=, locationId=6]
```

The output that got printed out above is coming from the toString method that I've inside the EmployeeLocation class.

However, I believe as soon as it goes to the for loop, I get the following error.

```
[INFO]  java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.pending.model.EmployeeLocation cannot be cast 
to class java.lang.String (com.pending.model.EmployeeLocation is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @7fae4d4a;
 java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

EmployeeLocation is a class and it has getters and setters for id, name, description, comment and locationId. I want loop over the above EmployeeLocation object and get the id (83 and 84 respectively ) inside the loop.

How should I go about it?

Comment: The parameter you passed to `getEmployeeLocationByQuery` is _highly suggestive_ that you are writing code which is SQL injectable (not using prepared statements, concatening input directly into the query string). This is a **security issue**, one which you should correct ASAP if this is public-facing software.

Comment: That all said, the problem is you have a `List<EmployeeLocation>`, which you've assigned to a `List<String>`. This might be caused by some oddness in the method signature of `getEmployeeLocationByQuery` (e.g. a `<T> List<T>` return, or some weird casting), but overall in doing this you've doomed your first access from the list to throw that CCE. So use the correct type of list for your variable, and the correct type of element for your `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For printing the list directly, you're getting away with an incorrect usage of generics.  You are assigning your results to a `List<String>`.  The only way this could compile is if `getEmployeeLocationByQuery` is returning a `List<String>`, a raw `List`, or as suggested by a comment above, a `List<T>`.

Because the last part of the code has the `ClassCastException`, it looks like that method is returning a different kind of list than the type of the variable `locationList`.  You may be getting an unchecked assignment warning when compiling because of this if it's returning a raw `List`.

The first part of the code passes the `List` to [the overload of `System.out.println` that takes an `Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object)).  Then it uses [`String.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)), which yields your output as expected.  Because the specific type of `String` wasn't needed, an implicit cast was not inserted here attempting to cast your `List` to a `String`, so no error occurred.

However, with your foreach loop, an implicit cast to the specific type is inserted by the compiler, resulting in your `ClassCastException`.  The [JLS, Section 14.14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2), gives the equivalent code for an enhanced for loop, showing the inserted cast:

```
for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
    {VariableModifier} T Identifier = (TargetType) #i.next();
    Statement
}
```

Use the proper type parameter for the `List`, and the proper type for the foreach loop:

```
// Change List<String> to List<EmployeeLocation> here.
List<EmployeeLocation> locationList = getEmployeeLocationByQuery("name LIKE'"+searchName+"%'");
System.out.println("print location");
System.out.println(locationList);

// Change loop variable type to EmployeeLocation, name it better.
for (EmployeeLocation location : locationList) {
    System.out.println("Inside Loop");
    System.out.println(location);
}
```

As an aside, as suggested in a comment above, you need to fix your [SQL injection vulnerability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024894/sql-injection-vulnerability-thru-preparedstatement).

Comment: Thanks. No error this time after changing that. `[INFO] Inside Loop
[INFO]EmployeeLocation [id=83, name=firstname, description=tetetyet, comment=, locationId=6]
[INFO] Inside Loop
[INFO]EmployeeLocation [id=84, name=secondname, description=test, comment=, locationId=6]` But how do I retrieve `id` variable from there?

Comment: I have to assume your `EmployeeLocation` class has a getter method for `id`?

Comment: Yes. `location.getId()` works. Thanks very much.